# Broadcast receiver in a separate process

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

Hi i have developed a android app. It contain a service with separate process. I want communicate from my service to MainActivity. If i not use a separate process it work, but if make a separate process, MainActivity doesn't receive broadcast.
Here , Manifest:

```
application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".BluetoothLeService$MyReceiver"/>

    <service android:name=".BluetoothLeService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":service"/>
```

This is in my Service:

```
    public void sendResult(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("ui");
    if(message != null)
        intent.putExtra("updateui", message);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver),
            new IntentFilter("ui")
    );
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onStop();
}
...
......

receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String s = intent.getStringExtra("updateui");
            Log.d("stringa s ",s);
            if(s.equals("1")) set_color();
    }
}
```

how i edit my code for my separate process???
Thank you

SOLVED: I have removed the localbroadcast!!

Comment: check this line: broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent); What is broadcaster in your service, just use method Context.sendBroadcast()

Comment: Doesn't work...mh... but localbroadcast work with separate process??